# Change default behavior of the Dojo DnD plugin on EnhancedGrid

Tags: javascript, datagrid, dojo, drag-and-drop

I'm using Dojo 1.8 for an application I'm working on and I'm trying to create a file browser of sorts (à la Dropbox).  I'm using an EnhancedGrid to display the list of files and directories, along with Dojo's DnD plugin for that grid.

I want to be able to limit the DnD functionality so that if a user drags a row(s) they can only drop them on a row which represents a directory; that is, I want the mouse icon to reflect whether or not they can drop, and disable the drop events for rows that *aren't* directories.  I've combed through the source of the packaged DnD plugin, but I can't find any sort of eventing or configuration that I could manipulate, although I could just be looking in the wrong places.

So, S.O., is this functionality:
a) possible with Dojo as-is
b) do-able with a quick bit of new code
or
c) do-able only through extensive new code?